# Using Custom Accessor In Laravel Eloquent Relationships

Tags: php, laravel

I have an `Album` model in my Laravel Application in which I have defined a relationship like:

```
final public function user(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

I have created a custom accessor in my `User` model like this:

```
final public function getFullNameAttribute(): string
{
    return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
}
```

Now when I query the database like this:

```
return response()->json(Album::with('user:id,full_name')->get(), 200);
```

It throws an error:

```
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'full_name' in 'field list' (SQL: select `id`, `full_name` from `users` where `users`.`id` in (3, 5))
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding `full_name` to `with('user:id,full_name')`, you may update your `User` model by adding `public $appends = ['full_name'];`

and updating `with` like `with('user')` will append full_name to your user models automatically.

Another alternative would be adding required columns into the relationship method such as;

```
final public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class)->select(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name']);
}
```

Comment: Well it worked, but now it is showing full_name with only middle space. First Name and Last Name is absent :/

Comment: I will update the answer with alternatives @MuhammadWaqar